# Custom contents <td> in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms

The prop `student.gender` returns 0 or 1 from Api, I want to custom it will be come either `<i class="fas fa-male"></i>` with 1 or `<i class="fas fa-female"></i>` with 0. How can I do it? Below is my code:

```js
{students.map((student, idx) => {
  return (
    <tr key={student.id}>
      <td>{idx + 1}</td>
      <td>{student.stuId}</td>
      <td>{student.firstName}</td>
      <td>{student.lastName}</td>
      <td>{student.gender}</td>
      <td>{student.phone}</td>
      <td>{student.email}</td>
      <td>{student.majorId}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => handleModalShow(null, student.id)}>
          <i className="fas fa-edit text-primary"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => deleteStudent(null, student.id)}>
          <i className="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

Comment: use iternary operator, or put it in a function, or a new component

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator to create the class name from the `student.gender` prop.

```js
<td>
  <i className={`fas fa-${student.gender === 1 ? 'male' : 'female'}`}></i>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator

```
{ student.gender==1?<i class="fas fa-male"></i> : <i class="fas fa-female"></i>
}
```

This will select the image that you want based the results of the comparison.

You can also determine the image you want before the return statement:

```
 var genderimage=student.gender==1?<i class="fas fa-male"></i> : <i class="fas fa-female"></i>
   return ( ...<td> {genderimage}</td>)
```